# How to specify that a package uses my key bindings

Tags: key-bindings, use-package

For example, I use `M-s` as `isearch-forward`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-s") 'isearch-forward)
```

When I try to install `isearch+` with `use-package`:

```
(use-package isearch+
 :straight t)
```

I get the following error:

```
(error "Key sequence M-s h d starts with non-prefix key M-s")"
```

This happens with all packages where `M-s` is somehow used.

How do I fix this globally so that packages respect my keybindings?

Comment: You need to remap `search-map` but it's not as straightforward as remapping a function. Maybe https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/8apn20/how_to_properly_remap_emacs_prefix_keys_cc_and_cx/, and, linked therein, https://github.com/darkstego/rebinder.el, can be of help.